# php - scandir and return matched files

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am trying to get a matched array of files using `scandir()` and `foreach()`.

when I run `scandir()` then it returns all file list. Its okey here.

now in second step when I do foreach `scandir()`s array then I get only one matched file. but there are two files called (please note before doing foreach my scandir() returns all files including this two files);

```
widget_lc_todo.php
widget_lc_notes.php
```

something is missing in my code, I dont know what :-(

here is my code:

```
$path = get_template_directory().'/templates';
$files = scandir($path);
print_r($files);
$template = array();
foreach ($files as $file){      
    if(preg_match('/widget_lc?/', $file)):
         $template[] = $file;
         return $template;

    endif;
}
print_r($template);
```

Comment: You are calling `return` right after you find the first matching file.

Comment: What a big dumb I am, Thanks man you rocks

Comment: Sometimes we just need an extra pair of eyes on the code :)

Comment: You are right, I spent more then 3 hours just solving this, but you solved in one sec.. Thanks dear

Comment: @Andrew, Write that comment as an answer and OP, select that answer. So, the question doesn't stay 'open'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code above is calling `return` as soon as it finds the first matching file, which means that the foreach loop exits as soon as `preg_match` returns true. You should not return until after the foreach loop exits:

```
// ...
foreach ($files as $file){      
    if(preg_match('/widget_lc?/', $file)) {
         $template[] = $file;
    }
}
return $template;
// ...
```